Forming Sentences
I have a bunch of transcripts from online videos but I suspect the transcripts aren't formatted well. There are no punctuations, sentences are broken abruptly, some words aren't complete (for example Let is written as et) and some words do not add to the meaning of the content like 'uh', 'um' etc. For the last case I have a function that detects and remove a few filler words that people often use while speaking. I want to use this data to fine tune an LLM. For the purposes of creating sentences, I used the spacy.load() method. However, I'm unsure if there is a way to complete broken words and improve the sentence formation.
Doing this manually isn't possible since the data is extremely large. I have about 30 videos each of which are about an hour long.
Fwiw, I'm getting my transcript directly from youtube using the show transcript option. If you think using a 3rd party transcriber would help, then I'm willing to try that, so feel free to suggest.
Thanks in advance!

This belongs on Software Recommendations.

To someone else reading this, I think one way to solve this problem would be using AWS Transcribe. It is paid and cost me about $1.3/hr of audio but the quality was very very impressive.
